# Is there any upper bound for the number of ways we can partition a multiset, where each part/segment in the partition has distinct elements?

Tags: time-complexity, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, partitions

A question is asked in the below link, which asks for the number of cases we can partition a multiset, where each part/segment in the partition has distinct elements.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622246/how-many-ways-we-can-partition-a-multiset-where-each-part-segment-in-the-partit?noredirect=1#comment9752441_4622246

I am looking for the computational complexity of finding the number of ways for the partitioning or an upper bound for the algorithm doing so. The parameters are in the given link.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You have been given an algorithm; you should be able to analyze its running time.  What progress have you made on that?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: D.W.: I am wondering what the computational complexity of an efficient algorithm for this problem is. Do you have any idea? The question seems not to be straightforward as nobody has answered it yet. I asked this question on math.stackexchange, and it remained unanswered for two weeks, so I closed my question there and asked it here with the hope that computer scientists at least can help me in this regard.

Comment: I suggest that you include in the question your analysis of the running time of the algorithm that was provided to you.